# WPF Wrap ListView, or Grid DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

i am trying to make a XAML with wrapping list view, or is it a grid, or table. I am just not sure. Please take a look at the image. How would i go about formatting my "list" that needs to wrap around the view, can someone please give me sample XAML, as i have no idea how to realize how to make this view.

[image]

It seems i need to use a ListView inside a Wrappanel of some sort? The data is dynamic, such as i can have any number of key/value pairs as seen here (open, high, lose, close, etc...) so keep in mind the pairs can have any number and they need to wrap around the control/window.

Any idea how to define such a XAML?

Thanks.

Comment: Why? can someone please help me, i am stuck here.

Comment: I see you found your answer. In the future, you should put more effort in describing exactly what you want to happen. We readers know nothing about, how you want to align your items, how you want to order them, in what direction you want to expand / shrink your panel... the scope of your question is unclear since your image contains more than just a list of key/value pairs. Your answer is far from your image - how would anyone know that's what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since figured it out. I'm using an itemcontrol instead of a list and put a wrappanel. Like this.

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding KeyText}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding ValueText}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```